# PHP: file_exists() not working properly.

Tags: php

`file_exists()` does not seem to be working properly for me. It defaults right to the else statement, blank_user.png. But it does display without the  `file_exists()` check in the last img in my code. I can't figure out what's going wrong.

```
<?php 
    $filename = "/project/images/user_image/" . $username . ".png";
    if(file_exists($filename)){ ?>
    <img src = "<?php echo '/project/images/user_image/' . $username . '.png';?>" alt = "User Pic" height = 280 width = 280 />

<?  
    } else {  ?>
    <img src = "<?php echo '/project/images/user_image/default/blank_user.png';?>" alt = "User Pic" height = 280 width = 280 />
<? } ?>
</br>
    <img src = "<?php echo '/project/images/user_image/' . $username . '.png';?>" alt = "User Pic" height = 280 width = 280 />
?>
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump($filename, file_exists($filename)); die;` and nothing else. What do you get?

Comment: Just a quick tip: You can rewrite the `<?php echo` as `<?=`. Makes for some cleaner code.

Comment: Also, `file_exists()` uses an *absolute* path, so here it's looking for `/project`.

Comment: `/project...` the `/` means you starting from the root of the file system, are you sure that's the right location?

Comment: string(36) "/project/images/user_image/user1.png" bool(false). The file definitely exists, though. It's displaying it properly in my last line of code above.

Comment: That's because your *webserver* handles relative links, but PHP's `file_exists()` does not. You've set Apache (or nginx or whatever) to say that when you go to `/projects`, it actually goes to X directory. You need to use a relative link in your PHP code, which requires you to use `__DIR__` and then get the right directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `file_exists()` takes an **absolute** path. It is not broken for you, you are just passing an incorrect path that does not exist. What you are looking for is a **relative** path.

In your current solution, you are looking for `/project` in the root of the filesystem, which I almost guarantee you don't want.

To use a relative path instead, you will need to use `__DIR__ . '/../relative/path/here'`, where `__DIR__` is the currently executing PHP file's directory.